# how to show/hide widget in tkinter without moving other widget

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm using `grid_remove()` and `grid()` command to hide/show the widget but the result is the other widget is move out of the original position.

How to hide/show the widget without moving widget

Example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


GUI = Tk()
GUI.title("myTest")
GUI.geometry("700x700")

Nameget = StringVar()
Priceget = StringVar()
Quantityget = StringVar()
Unitget = StringVar()
Partnumget = StringVar()

L_Partnum = ttk.Label(GUI, text = 'Part number')
L_Partnum.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

L_namme = ttk.Label(GUI, text = 'Name')
L_namme.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

L_quan = ttk.Label(GUI, text = 'Quantity')
L_quan.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
L_quan.grid_remove()

L_price = ttk.Label(GUI, text = 'Price')
L_price.grid(row = 3, column = 3)

E_partnum = ttk.Entry(GUI, textvariable = Partnumget)
E_partnum.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

E_namme = ttk.Entry(GUI,textvariable = Nameget)
E_namme.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

E_unit = ttk.Entry(GUI,textvariable = Unitget)

E_quan = ttk.Entry(GUI,textvariable = Quantityget)
E_quan.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
E_quan.grid_remove()

E_price = ttk.Entry(GUI,textvariable = Priceget)
E_price.grid(row = 4, column = 3)

I_check_vat = IntVar()

def d_check_vat_1():
    E_partnum.focus()
    if I_check_vat.get() == 1:
        L_quan.grid()
        E_quan.grid()
    elif I_check_vat.get() == 0:
        L_quan.grid_remove()
        E_quan.grid_remove()

C_CHECK_VAT = ttk.Checkbutton(GUI, text="click here to see the result", variable=I_check_vat, command=d_check_vat_1)
C_CHECK_VAT.grid(row = 5, column = 0)

GUI.mainloop()
```

Before clicking:

[image]

After clicking:

[image]

image with the expected output:
[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @BryanOakley code updated

Comment: You want it to be all straight line?

Comment: You can set the `minsize` of the row and column the same as the size of the widgets.

Comment: @CoolCloud I want the 'E_price '  fix at row = 4, column = 3. as you can see, when 'E_quan' has been removed the 'E_price ' is moving to the position of 'E_quan'

Comment: That is because these numbers are relative. If you want to place the widget in the 100th row and there is no 99 rows, it will be place in the last empty row.

Comment: so how can I place in the 100th row by leave blank the first 99th row?

Comment: Can you make an image with the expected output?

Comment: @CoolCloud updated

Comment: @acw1668  the error is  'Entry' object has no attribute 'minsize'

Comment: It is a problem that empty space cannot be left by `grid()`. Maybe use `place()`?

Comment: `minsize` is set by calling `.rowconfigure()` and `.columnconfigure()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `grid()` does not take up empty space by default, it gives the last empty row/col to the widget(if previous rows before it are empty).

So what you can do is, set minimum space for your column and row so that those space will remain empty, so change your function to:

```
def d_check_vat_1():
    E_partnum.focus()
    if I_check_vat.get():
        L_quan.grid(row=2, column=2)
        E_quan.grid(row=3, column=2)
        
        width = E_quan.winfo_reqwidth() # Get widget width
        height = L_quan.winfo_reqheight() # Get widget height
        
        GUI.rowconfigure(2,minsize=height) # Now apply the values
        GUI.rowconfigure(3,minsize=height)
        GUI.columnconfigure(2,minsize=width)
    
    else:
        L_quan.grid_remove()
        E_quan.grid_remove()
```

Now its dynamic as well, it takes the width of widget and applies that as the `minsize` of that row so that row will have that empty space.

Comment: I change a bit on your code and it totally work! thank you.